# ReactJS ES6 limit lines and characters from a textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, textarea, rows

I was searching for some ways to limit the lines and chars for a textarea with react and es6.
I found a few ways but they dont realy work for all browsers like e.key, where i could limit chars for a line.
I would like to have a text area where i can only have 5 lines and 40 chars each line.

It should be like

```
Line 1 -> 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Line 2 -> 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Line 3 -> 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Line 4 -> 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Line 5 -> 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

What i already tried:

```
add(event){
    let allowedLines = 4;
    let lineLength = 40;
    let maxTextLength = 200;

    if(!(this.state.textAreaValue.length % lineLength)){
        this.setState({
            textAreaValue: this.state.textAreaValue + "\n"
        });
    }

    let maxLines = this.state.textAreaValue.split("\n");
    if(this.state.textAreaValue < maxTextLength
        && maxLines.length <= allowedLines){

        this.setState({
            textAreaValue: this.state.textAreaValue + event.key
        });
    }
}
render(){
    let textValue = this.state.textAreaValue;
    return (
        <textarea className="textArea-big" id="textarea" rows="5" cols="40"
        placeholer="some placeholer here" onKeyPress={this.add} value={textValue} />
    );
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, found a solution but i think there could be a better way.
Here is my solution:

```
setTextAreaFormat() {
    let lines = [];
    let text = "";
    let maxLines = 5;
    let maxTextForLine = 40;
    text = document.getElementById("textarea").value;

    if(text.length >= maxTextForLine){
        lines = text.match(/.{1,35}/g);
    }
    if(lines.length > maxLines){
        lines.length = maxLines;
    }
    if(lines.length > 0){
        document.getElementById("textarea").value = lines.join("\n");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("textarea").value = text;
    }
}
```